# random constraint behaviour

Tags: java, mysql, sql, hibernate

I try to insert 1 value into table 'beleg_kopf', then inserting 1 value into 'beleg_kunden' and then inserting 1 to n values into 'beleg_positionen'. Foreign keys can be seen in the SQL code.
When my PC is normal fast, the insertion always fails due to a foreign key constraint failure. But when my PC is crazy slow then it works correctly.

That error is simply a lie as the rows get inserted incorrect order and when the PC is so slow that every INSERT takes half a minute the next INSERT recognizes the already existing row in the previous table. But with normal execution speed, Hibernate forgets that the value is already there.

The problem is almost impossible to reconstruct and it occurs completely random.

**Error Message:**

> MySQLIntegrityConstraintViolationException: Cannot add or update a
>   child row: a foreign key constraint fails (`beleg_kunden`, CONSTRAINT
>   `bkd_belegnr` FOREIGN KEY (`belegnr`) REFERENCES `beleg_kopf`
>   (`belegnr`) ON UPDATE CASCADE)

**SQL DDL:**

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `beleg_kopf` (
  `belegnr` INT(8) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `auftrag` INT(9) NOT NULL,
  `typ` VARCHAR(1) NOT NULL,
  `datum` DATE NOT NULL,
  `payterms` INT(2) NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`belegnr`)
ENGINE = InnoDB;

CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `beleg_kunden` (
  `belegnr` INT(8) NOT NULL,
  `kdnr` INT(5) NOT NULL,
  `typ` INT(2) NOT NULL,
  `name` VARCHAR(80) NOT NULL,
  `vorname` VARCHAR(80) NULL,
  `strasse` VARCHAR(80) NULL,
  `hausnr` VARCHAR(15) NULL,
  `adresse2` VARCHAR(80) NULL,
  `plz` VARCHAR(10) NOT NULL,
  `ort` VARCHAR(80) NOT NULL,
  `land` INT(3) NOT NULL,
  `uid` VARCHAR(30) NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`belegnr`),
  CONSTRAINT `bkd_belegnr`
    FOREIGN KEY (`belegnr`)
    REFERENCES `beleg_kopf` (`belegnr`)
    ON DELETE RESTRICT
    ON UPDATE CASCADE
ENGINE = InnoDB;

CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `beleg_positionen` (
  `id` INT NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `belegnr` INT(8) NOT NULL,
  `anzahl` DECIMAL(7,2) UNSIGNED NOT NULL,
  `einheit` VARCHAR(15) NULL,
  `bezeichnung` VARCHAR(200) NOT NULL,
  `preis` DECIMAL(8,2) NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`),
  INDEX `bpos_belegnr_idx` (`belegnr` ASC),
  CONSTRAINT `bpos_belegnr`
    FOREIGN KEY (`belegnr`)
    REFERENCES `beleg_kopf` (`belegnr`)
    ON DELETE RESTRICT
    ON UPDATE CASCADE)
ENGINE = InnoDB;
```

**Hibernate Code:**

```
@Entity
@Table(name="beleg_kopf")
@SequenceGenerator(name="belegnr", initialValue = 1, allocationSize = 1)
public class BelegKopf implements BaseDTO {
    @Id
    @Column(name="belegnr", nullable = false, length = 8)
    @GeneratedValue(strategy=GenerationType.AUTO)
    private int belegnr;

    @Column(name="auftrag", nullable = false, length = 9)
    private int auftrag;

    @Column(name="typ", nullable = false, length = 2)
    private char typ;

    @Column(name="datum", nullable = false)
    @Temporal(TemporalType.DATE)
    private Date datum;

    @Column(name="payterms", nullable = true, length = 2)
    private int payterms;

    ...
}

@Entity
@Table(name="beleg_kunden")
public class BelegKunde implements BaseDTO {
    @Id
    @Column(name="belegnr", nullable = false, length = 8)
    private int belegnr;

    @Column(name="kdnr", nullable = false, length = 5)
    private int kdnr;

    @Column(name="typ", nullable = false, length = 2)
    private int typ;

    @Column(name="name", nullable = false, length = 80)
    private String name;

    @Column(name="vorname", nullable = true, length = 80)
    private String vorname;

    @Column(name="strasse", nullable = true, length = 80)
    private String strasse;

    @Column(name="hausnr", nullable = true, length = 15)
    private String hausnr;

    @Column(name="adresse2", nullable = true, length = 80)
    private String adresse2;

    @Column(name="plz", nullable = false, length = 10)
    private String plz;

    @Column(name="ort", nullable = false, length = 80)
    private String ort;

    @Column(name="land", nullable = false, length = 3)
    private int land;

    @Column(name="uid", nullable = true, length = 30)
    private String uid;

    ...
}

@Entity
@Table(name="beleg_positionen")
@SequenceGenerator(name="id", initialValue = 1, allocationSize = 1)
public class BelegPosition implements BaseDTO {
    @Id
    @Column(name="id", nullable = false)
    @GeneratedValue(strategy=GenerationType.AUTO)
    private int id;

    @Column(name="belegnr", nullable = false, length = 8)
    private int belegnr;

    @Column(name="anzahl", nullable = false, length = 7, precision = 2)
    private double anzahl;

    @Column(name="einheit", nullable = true, length = 15)
    private String einheit;

    @Column(name="bezeichnung", nullable = false, length = 200)
    private String bezeichnung;

    @Column(name="preis", nullable = false, length = 8, precision = 2)
    private double preis;

    ...
}
```

**Hibernate Insertion Code:**

```
public static void createBeleg(BelegKopf kopf, BelegKunde kunde, List<BelegPosition> pos) throws DatabaseException {
    Session hsession = null;
    Transaction htransaction = null;

    try {
        hsession = HibernateUtil.getSessionFactory().openSession();
        htransaction = hsession.beginTransaction();

        hsession.save(kopf);
        hsession.save(kunde);

        for (BelegPosition p : pos)
            hsession.save(p);

        htransaction.commit();
    } catch (HibernateException ex) {
        if (htransaction != null)
            htransaction.rollback();

        throw new DatabaseException(ex);
    } finally {
        if (hsession != null)
            hsession.close();
    }
}
```

Comment: It's not about Hibernate forgetting that the value is already there. It's just that the value is not there yet, because `save()` doesn't actually insert data in the table. It tells Hibernate that it will have to be inserted at flush time. Since you never flush yourself, and since, instead of defining associations between entities, you just use basic columns, Hibernate has no way to know in which order the inserts should be executed. Use associations, and it will. Or at least call flush() when you want to make sure something is actually inserted.

Comment: Also, the ID of kopf is supposed to be auto-generated, but you never read it to set it in the referencing entities.

Comment: Do not see any relationship between `BelegKopf` and `BelegKunde` in the entity classes. is your schema generated by Hibernate? or it's predefined?

Comment: @JBNizet The DB schema schemes to be pre-defined. There is no mapping between entities but I could see FK constraint in the Database.

Comment: @GovindaSakhare what's your point?

Comment: @JBNizet 1. When I call flush() is it - in the case of an Exception - still possible to revert the changes with my current code? 2. The ID is auto-generated but I know which ID the database will generate and so kunde and position already come with the correct ID which will be generated.
The Hibernate schema code is predefined. But I can alter it. But please help me with that, as I am not familiar with using foreign keys in Hibernate.

Comment: 1. yes, of course. flush just tells Hibernate to execute the pending queries. Not to commit. 2. No, you really don't. two transactions could insert in parallel to the table, and there's no way to reliably predict that. Don't make such assumptions. 3. Hibernate has a free, well-written user guide for that. Read it. https://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/orm/current/userguide/html_single/Hibernate_User_Guide.html#associations

Comment: @JBNizet Thank you for your help! I'm now flushing and reading back the ID and now it works fine.